# What common device uses 7 pin mini DIN plugs, that could be used for the Roomba serial port?

Tags: roomba

I have a Roomba that I'm planning to hack on the cheap, using junk cables and other parts. The excellent book *Hacking Roomba* suggests using Macintosh serial cables as a cheap surrogate.

However, as a hopeless Macintosh aficionado, I am somewhat loath to start chopping up my precious Mac cables. Plus the 8 pin Mac cables aren't an *exact* match anyway

So, I was wondering what other, hopefully commonly available, devices use a 7 pin mini DIN plug, that could be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Electronics sell the cables...

https://core-electronics.com.au/mini-din-connector-cable-for-irobot-create-2-7-pins-6-feet.html?utm_source=google_shopping&gclid=CjwKCAiAx8KQBhAGEiwAD3EiP3lPsVEOb1lMni_NlwosKJn3eBxhbsDlLSWiARWlqn-ZYJkN7FcUTBoCHPcQAvD_BwE

you can also find the plugs on ebay, just google "ebay roomba din plug"